# mysql data transfer between tables

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table 'Table A' with columns:

```
country,
 state, 
unique_id ( which is auto increment) 
....... 60 columns
```

I need to create Table B with Table A stucture plus 1 more coloumn 'Newcoloumn' and transfer the data from Table A to Table B.

Note : Table A has 12 million records and 14 indexes on it. Inno DB is the engine used.

As of Now, I follow the below steps

1. create a new table with the new column
2. Insert into new table (columns) select (columns) from old table and just copy 1 million records since it consumes more time.

I need to copy the whole data 12 million records in less than 10 minutes?
Which is the  fastest method to do this? Any help?

Comment: Try not to add any indexes in table B, or use PHPMyAdmin to duplicate the table and add the new_column after the duplicate.

Comment: maybe mysqldump ist the right tool for this job.